# very slow kubuntu load time

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 20.04

I'm getting a very slow boot on my thinkpad laptop with i5 6th gen, 8 ram and 1 To HDD
this is my dmsg output :

```
[    1.303559] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    1.312050] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20190822 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    1.313682] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.314732] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    1.315064] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
[    1.464919] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6544, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.464921] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.464922] usb 1-1: Product: TransMemory     
[    1.464923] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA 
[    1.464924] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 54B80A3FA779C18100027640
[    1.514306] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.514307] fbcon: Deferring console take-over
[    1.514309] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    1.593855] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.746792] usb 1-3: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 12 but max is 4
[    1.746794] usb 1-3: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 13 but max is 4
[    1.746794] usb 1-3: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 13 but max is 4
[    1.746795] usb 1-3: config 1 has no interface number 1
[    1.746796] usb 1-3: config 1 has no interface number 4
[    1.748317] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1199, idProduct=9079, bcdDevice= 0.06
[    1.748319] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.748320] usb 1-3: Product: Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
[    1.748321] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
[    1.748322] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: LF63911203031014
[    1.778118] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    1.797573] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    1.797576] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.835401] ata2.00: ATA-10: ST1000LM035-1RK172, SDM1, max UDMA/133
[    1.835404] ata2.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    1.867533] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    1.867536] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.881859] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    1.905325] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.914957] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST1000LM035-1RK1 SDM1 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.915382] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.915409] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[    1.915411] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.915423] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.915425] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.915455] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.926066] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2496.013 MHz
[    1.926072] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x23fa83802b9, max_idle_ns: 440795289750 ns
[    1.926264] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.010683]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6
[    2.011958] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.034671] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2b, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    2.034673] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.080463] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5676], y [..4758]
[    2.111436] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1096..]
[    2.111440] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: LEN2016 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    2.169680] usb 1-10: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.172145] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.2, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xf006a3/0x943300/0x12e800/0x10000, board id: 3053, fw id: 2010421
[    2.172149] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
[    2.210705] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[    2.335591] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0706, bcdDevice= 0.12
[    2.335593] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.335594] usb 1-10: Product: Integrated Camera
[    2.335595] usb 1-10: Manufacturer: SunplusIT Inc
[    2.343008] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    2.343171] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[    2.343280] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.344235] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    2.860627] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    3.082521] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input7
[    3.380834] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  TransMemory      1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[    3.381206] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    3.381447] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 30310400 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.5 GiB)
[    3.381654] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.381655] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
[    3.381861] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.399931]  sdb: sdb1
[    3.400924] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    4.139964] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    4.223724] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) c8:5b:76:83:6a:b8
[    4.223725] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    4.223781] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: 1000FF-0FF
[    4.224625] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
[    5.382517] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    7.601382] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    7.835888] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    7.854183] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    7.901156] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <anas-ThinkPad-T460>.
[   10.006189] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   10.224808] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/vpnagentd.service:10: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/vpnagentd.pid → /run/vpnagentd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   10.528736] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket:6: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/docker.sock → /run/docker.sock; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   10.630103] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[   10.630426] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[   10.630634] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   10.630692] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   10.630891] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   10.630933] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[   10.630943] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   10.630950] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   10.631096] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[   10.631164] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   10.631202] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   10.631346] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   10.631411] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   10.631490] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   10.631564] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   10.631626] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   10.632479] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   10.633404] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[   10.634745] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[   10.635999] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[   10.637631] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[   10.638597] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[   10.639633] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[   10.639687] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
[   10.760671] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[   10.760719] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
[   10.763100] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   10.763933] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[   10.764773] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[   10.765620] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[   10.767511] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   10.767698] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   10.767801] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[   10.767896] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[   10.777449] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[   10.790296] systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
[   10.886989] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   10.888959] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[   10.889976] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
[   10.890025] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
[   10.891171] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[   10.892364] systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
[   10.988976] systemd[1]: Finished udev Coldplug all Devices.
[   11.148705] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   11.233888] systemd-journald[423]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[   11.466835] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   11.559435] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   14.039310] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   14.080931] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[   14.083360] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   14.145227] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[   14.145229] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[   14.145547] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   14.238457] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 5 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[   14.238459] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[   14.238459] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[   14.238460] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
[   14.238461] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[   14.238461] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain psys 2^-14 Joules
[   14.274143] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   14.274145] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   14.274893] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.662191] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[   14.919364] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[   14.919366] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[   14.919367] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   14.919367] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[   15.206458] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.26
[   15.206459] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[   15.206460] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS R06ET67W (1.41 ), EC R06HT31W
[   15.206461] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T460, model 20FMS64X01
[   15.208115] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
[   15.208132] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[   15.208133] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[   15.211456] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[   15.212806] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_wwan_sw: radio is unblocked
[   15.223448] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
[   15.233511] thinkpad_acpi: battery 1 registered (start 45, stop 65)
[   15.233517] battery: new extension: ThinkPad Battery Extension
[   15.233577] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input8
[   15.764278] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   15.855330] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC293: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   15.855332] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   15.855334] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=2 (0x16/0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   15.855335] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   15.855335] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   15.855336] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Dock Mic=0x19
[   15.855337] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x1a
[   15.855338] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[   15.912251] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
[   15.912305] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
[   15.912355] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
[   15.912413] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
[   15.912470] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[   15.912519] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[   15.912567] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[   15.912616] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
[   15.912666] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
[   15.919952] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[   15.927914] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   15.928688] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   15.997384] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: e4:a7:a0:b4:cd:46
[   16.072205] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   16.072582] thermal thermal_zone3: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[   16.170040] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   18.534261] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   18.571192] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   18.571216] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   18.571217] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.571286] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.571288] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.571292] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.579978] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   18.595839] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   18.595847] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   18.695309] usbcore: registered new interface driver qcserial
[   18.695317] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Qualcomm USB modem
[   18.695861] qcserial 1-3:1.0: Qualcomm USB modem converter detected
[   18.695952] usb 1-3: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   18.696484] qcserial 1-3:1.2: Qualcomm USB modem converter detected
[   18.696545] usb 1-3: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   18.696963] qcserial 1-3:1.3: Qualcomm USB modem converter detected
[   18.697008] usb 1-3: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   18.766025] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   18.770119] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 10 week 41 2018
[   18.772030] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[   18.826117] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[   18.866853] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (5986:0706)
[   18.885496] uvcvideo 1-10:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[   18.885499] uvcvideo 1-10:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[   18.885501] uvcvideo 1-10:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[   18.885502] uvcvideo 1-10:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   18.885574] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/input/input18
[   18.885662] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   18.885662] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   18.943387] cdc_mbim 1-3:1.12: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[   18.943618] cdc_mbim 1-3:1.12 wwan0: register 'cdc_mbim' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, CDC MBIM, 3e:d8:91:b6:e4:1a
[   18.943676] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_mbim
[   21.950123] Adding 3906556k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:3906556k FS
[   23.388626] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.838:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1014 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.388629] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.838:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1014 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.388631] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.838:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=1013 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.392671] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.842:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1012 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.392687] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.842:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=1012 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.392689] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.842:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1012 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.392690] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.842:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" pid=1012 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.394628] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.846:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=1015 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.394631] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.846:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=1015 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.419348] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110853.870:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=1016 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   46.455625] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   46.455631] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   46.455644] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   46.504620] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[   47.237988] kauditd_printk_skb: 23 callbacks suppressed
[   47.237990] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110877.690:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=1175 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[   53.027358] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 1283
[   53.028717] Started bpfilter
[   54.555630] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   54.705189] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   54.786431] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   57.953624] aufs 5.4.3-20200302
[   74.361017] audit: type=1400 audit(1593110904.810:36): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=3110 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   81.108387] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   81.108395] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   81.108400] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   87.115242] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   87.146123] Bridge firewalling registered
[   88.134556] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   93.112368] acpi_call: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   93.112549] acpi_call: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  136.589814] wlp4s0: authenticate with 34:e8:94:2d:77:9f
[  136.601224] wlp4s0: send auth to 34:e8:94:2d:77:9f (try 1/3)
[  136.610442] wlp4s0: authenticated
[  136.611263] wlp4s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[  136.617773] wlp4s0: associate with 34:e8:94:2d:77:9f (try 1/3)
[  136.624082] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 34:e8:94:2d:77:9f (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=6)
[  136.632729] wlp4s0: associated
[  137.859480] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[  160.649529] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

this is my systemd-analyze blame output :

```
31.544s docker.service                                                           
26.209s systemd-journal-flush.service                                            
21.045s snapd.service                                                            
17.054s networkd-dispatcher.service                                              
16.450s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                       
10.445s accounts-daemon.service                                                  
10.003s dev-sda5.device                                                          
 9.796s udisks2.service                                                          
 6.953s smartmontools.service                                                    
 6.369s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
 5.873s lightdm.service                                                          
 5.495s gpu-manager.service                                                      
 5.294s ModemManager.service                                                     
 5.005s polkit.service                                                           
 4.653s NetworkManager.service                                                   
 4.499s avahi-daemon.service                                                     
 4.498s bluetooth.service                                                        
 4.212s dev-loop3.device                                                         
 3.841s grub-common.service                                                      
 3.691s apport.service                                                           
 3.373s thermald.service                                                         
 3.369s systemd-logind.service                                                   
 3.366s wpa_supplicant.service                                                   
 3.194s dev-loop1.device                                                         
 2.994s dev-loop2.device                                                         
 2.982s preload.service                                                          
 2.929s dev-loop9.device                                                         
 2.928s dev-loop8.device                                                         
 2.910s dev-loop7.device                                                         
 2.574s dev-loop4.device                                                         
 2.512s dev-loop0.device                                                         
 2.445s dev-loop5.device                                                         
 2.418s dev-loop6.device                                                         
 2.245s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                             
 2.127s systemd-resolved.service                                                 
 2.027s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                      
 1.495s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-092D\x2d1476.service                    
 1.322s apparmor.service                                                         
 1.312s tlp.service                                                              
 1.267s rsyslog.service                                                          
 1.244s systemd-modules-load.service                                             
 1.222s vpnagentd.service                                                        
 1.165s snapd.seeded.service                                                     
 1.148s alsa-restore.service                                                     
 1.129s lm-sensors.service                                                       
 1.122s e2scrub_reap.service
```

Comment: You can disable the service ```NetworkManager-wait-online.service``` via ```sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service```.It's merely there to load some programs in the systems that rely on other systems in the network to bootup.And you can disable the ```snapd.service``` too.Snaps programs automatically start the snap daemon once they get started.I don't see anything else is to improve.